# Can you implement custom fallbacks for Globalize3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize3

I'd like to have some custome fallbacks for Globalize3 on Rails.

I know you can set

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

and have untranslated text fallback to its default locale, but I would rather have something that would indicate it untranslated, something like a #not tnranslated# before or after the falled back text.

For example if the default locale text is

```
Foo bar
```

I would like the fallback text shown on an un translated text be

```
Foo bar #not translated!#
```

The only way I can figure to do this is have an if else around the text and check if the current locale is translated, and that doesn't seem to elegant, something like so.

```
<% if article.is_translated?(I18n.locale) %>
  <%= article.title %>
<% else %>
  <%= article.title %>#not translated#
<% end %>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a patch like this:

```
Globalize::ActiveRecord::Adapter.class_eval do
  def fetch(locale, name)
    record.globalize_fallbacks(locale).each do |fallback|
      value = stash.contains?(fallback, name) ? fetch_stash(fallback, name) : fetch_attribute(fallback, name)

      unless fallbacks_for?(value)
        set_metadata(value, :locale => fallback, :requested_locale => locale)
        return value if (fallback == locale)
        return value + " #not translated#"
      end
    end
    return nil
  end
end
```

In case it's not clear, the two lines that I changed are these ones:

```
        return value if (fallback == locale)
        return value + " #not translated#"
```